# How to get Frontier::Client / LWP to STOP verifying the SSL certificate in a CGI::Application web app?

Tags: perl, ssl, https, lwp

In dev and test environments, we are using self-signed SSL certs for a XMLRPC web service.  Production uses a nice 3rd party cert and cert verification works nicely, no problems there.

In the code of the calling application, which is a CGI::Application web app, we  skip the verification of the SSL certs in the dev and test environments only, knowing it would and should fail... or try to skip it.  Despite setting $ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} to 0 the call still fails with:

```
Error executing run mode 'myRunMode': 500 Can't connect to mydomain.com:443 (certificate verify failed)
```

A bunch of other (possibly deprecated by now?) env variables have been tried and we can't seem to get around this error in the web app.  At the command line, we *can* make a successful call which ignores cert verification with all the same code, and we've compared versions of all the Perl modules in play (LWP is at 6.15 in both cases for instance).

Online discussion points to different scenarios depending on which *SSL backend* is being used, so we experimented with installing LWP::Protocol::https and at least got different behavior.  We started failing with this instead just after the module installed:

```
Error executing run mode 'myRunMode': 404 Not Found
```

The 404 seems like a red herring but alas, removing LWP::Protocal::https gets us back to the 'certificate verification failed' error, so it seems like we might be on to something.

Does anyone have any ideas about how the skip the certificate verification in this CGI::Application environment?

Comment: LWP 6.15 is a version that has already had `LWP::Protocol::https` unbundled, so having that installed should be requirement for even starting to use HTTPS. Moving my `L::P::https` module away, I get an "LWP will support https URLs if the LWP::Protocol::https module is installed." error. One thing that might help with debugging is `perl -MCarp::Always` to always give you stack traces.
That and something like
`printf("%s => %s (MD5 %s)\n", $_, $INC{$_}, qx#md5sum $INC{$_}# =~ /^(\S+)/) for sort keys %INC;` somewhere near the error location to give you the list of modules actually in use.

Comment: Latest [LWP::UserAgent doc](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/libwww-perl-6.15/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm#ATTRIBUTES) says "The libwww-perl core no longer bundles protocol plugins for SSL. You will need to install LWP::Protocol::https separately to enable support for processing https-URLs."

Comment: Yes, that was my point: `LWP::Protocol::https` used to come with LWP but in your version it already doesn't. So if something is checking certs without you having this module installed, weird things are going on. Hence my suggestion to dump `%INC`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but still I'd like to share my solution.
Just add the following before doing frontier calls:

```
$ENV{'PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME'} = 0;
```

No need to change any frontier code or stuff ...

Answer (score 1):

[LWP::UserAgent::ssl_opts(verify_hostname => 0);](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-ssl_opts-key-value)

**--- UPDATE 5/17/16 330pm ---**

If you are okay with editing Frontier::Client (or just copy-pasting it and giving it a different package/file name) you can just replace use of LWP::UserAgent with WWW::Curl::Easy, which has been my go-to for SSL (I've got old version of LWP which uses libraries that have bugs). Here's curl code:

```
my ($rBody,$rHead); # response written here
my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new();
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $myRequest);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  \@myHeaders);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,   \$rBody);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, \$rHead);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
my $cc = $curl->perform();
```

You can even use HTTP::Response->parse($rHeadRegexed . $rBody) afterwards to get the same object returned by LWP::UserAgent->request(etc);

Comment: Since Frontier::Client uses LWP::UserAgent internally and does not expose all its options in its own API, I had to go into Frontier::Client itself and set this.  I tried both `new( ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 } )` as well as `ua->ssl_opts( verify_hostname => 0 )` to no avail.  Something nefarious is going on.